# How to create a user group that can only use one application?

Tags: users

I need create a special user group which is only allowed to login in to gnome and execute only one application.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not let the application replace your desktop environment in this special case?

Comment: @Takkat, if you know how to do this, you can ask a question about it and answer it yourself (providing as much detail as you can), then link it up in the comments here. That'd be cool.

Comment: @Takkat : yeah, can be that way too

Comment: see here: http://askubuntu.com/q/23932/3940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising, though a bit involved...

http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/ubuntu01.htm