# How to display just browser and protect it by password

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

I'd like to set up a PC with monitoring in the office. It should display some dashboard in a browser and a person should not be able to interact with it unless he or she for example knows the password. Perhaps it could just work as a sort of password protected screensaver displaying a predefined browser page. How can I achieve such result?

Comment: What about the normal _lock screen_ ?

Comment: You mean Alt+Ctrl+L? It doesn't display the browser while locked and that's what I'd like to achieve. To constantly display some webpage while preventing a random person from interacting with the PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a webbrowser on the screen saver or login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25635/running-a-webbrowser-on-the-screen-saver-or-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Install xtrlock (it's been around a long long time)

```
sudo apt install xtrlock
```

I just open the browser to the page I want and have a plugin refreshing the page at the interval desired.

Then open a terminal, and type:

```
sleep 5; xtrlock
```

This gives you 5 seconds to select the web browser and bring it into the foreground, hiding the terminal, and then it locks the screen. You have to enter the users password to unlock the screen.

Only down side is that it has a little lock icon where the mouse cursor would be, but I just move that into the corner.