# Is it possible to set up a separate session with GNOME Shell built from source as default?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, session

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3) explains how to build GNOME Shell from source thus preventing Unity wreckage. There's also a line which sets Shell as the default window manager at startup. I was wondering, would it be possible to create a new session which loads GNOME Shell on startup while keeping the other sessions (Unity and Classic GNOME) unaltered and usable? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in/31040#31040) and [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application/23933#23933) to different questions give instructions on how to define a **user defined session** that may be added to the list of sessions at startup from gdm. We need to add the setup as it was detailed in answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3).