# Add a new custom session?

Tags: gui, session

I would like to add a new session to the login screen (the thing where you select "Ubuntu, Ubuntu Classic, etc"  to install a new GUI on. How can I do this?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in/31040#31040) and [another answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application/23933#23933) may help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list on the logon screen is populated from the desktop files in the folder `/usr/share/xsessions`

The format of these files are similar - here is the Unity-2D desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Classic (No effects)
Comment=This session logs you into GNOME with the traditional panel without any 
graphical effect.
Exec=gnome-session --session=2d-gnome
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-2.0
```

All the files are root:root owned.

Creating or deleting desktop files in this folder creates or removes an entry in the drop-down list respectively.

[source](http://maketecheasier.com/customize-the-gdm-sessions-list/2010/08/08)