# CCSM is not working in GNOME and GNOME Classic 

Tags: compiz

Compiz config manager is not working in gnome and gnome classic and studio.

First I install ubuntu studio, then gnome desktop and classic inside it. what to do?

Is ubuntu studio not support ccsm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open terminal and type `compiz --replace` If that was succesfull then put that command in your startup and it will setup compiz on boot.

Comment: After that ccsm is not working...

Comment: Running `compiz --replace` with sudo is not a good idea. What do you mean by "setup compiz on boot"

Comment: @soundar You've marked this answer as the accepted answer, but your comment suggests it didn't work for you. If you're still looking for an answer to your problem, you should unaccept this (otherwise, people will not know you still want them to answer).

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad. I wanted to say that your compiz will be started along with your system, so you won't have to repeat that command manually. But if compiz is not working with that command try to type compiz --replace cpp and see if that works. I'm using this aproach and it's working, it worked in 11.10 and it's working now in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome-desktop uses [mutter window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_(window_manager)) instead of compiz. If you install Gnome-Classic *on top of Ubuntu*, you will have two sessions with gnome-classic. One with compiz (gnome-classic with effects) and another without compiz (gnome-classic without effects) .

***But, since you installed gnome-classic on top of Ubuntu studio, there will not be any gnome-classic session with compiz effects***. Because, Ubuntu Studio does not come with compiz as Ubuntu does.  Because UbuntuStudio uses XFCE desktop environment which is not using Compiz but XFWM.

You can try installing compiz and creating a custom session to be able to login with compiz effects.

See this question to get help of creating a custom session.

- [Add a new custom session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54507/61218)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with pygtk, with the python3 as default, when you have multi python environment in your system, the pygtk can not be imported, and cause this error, you can try with `python2 /usr/bin/ccsm`.
This is the solution solve my problem