# how to change session when on MacBuntu theme?

Tags: themes, session, xmonad, macbuntu

Learning about the Xmonad session, I downloaded it, but as of now I am unable to change session due to Macbuntu theme as it has no such selection criteria in Login screen, is there anyway to change session using CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
gnome-session --session=xmonad
```

Also consider looking at `man gnome-session`

From:
[How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

> i.e.
>
> `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
>
> change the line
>
> `user-session=ubuntu`

But in this case you would change the line that says user-session to: `user-session=xmonad`

Similar questions:

- [Add a new custom session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54507/add-a-new-custom-session)
- [How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in/31040#31040)
- [How do I replace the desktop by an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application/23933#23933)