# How to run a Python script for a specific user log in?

Tags: 12.04, python

I have written a python script and would like that to run for a specific user log in. The script has two images, one with the Windows logo and the other for Linux.

When the Windows logo is clicked it runs the `rdesktop` program and logs into the Windows box.

I have been looking for an example or help for the Linux image when clicked loads the Ubuntu desktop for that user.

Also where and how to run this script for a specific user? And if I can get this script to run on login for this user, will the image buttons be the only thing displayed until one of them is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

Either use the "Startup applications" or create a `.desktop` file in the directory

```
/home/user/.config/autostart/
```

..where `user` is the name of the user for which this script is supposed to run.

example /home/user.config/autostart/custom.desktop file would contain the following lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/user/script.sh
Name=Custom script
Comment=Custom Script
```

Comment: add the following lines to Your .desktop file (change it accordingly) `[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/user/script.sh
Name=Custom script
Comment=Custom Script`

Comment: I do not have the  /.config/autostart. I have found a autostart directory under /usr/share/gdm would that be that same as mentioned above

Comment: @user84627: if there is not yet an `autostart` directory in `.config` create one to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

We may not want the Unity desktop to be loaded on login in the case we only access a remote Windows desktop.

Then we may want to consider creating a [custom XSession](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application) that may then call our python script to determine the environment to load.