# How to shutdown the computer after Xsession ends?

Tags: shutdown, lightdm

I'm making a computer like an arcade machine with an academic game. I'm using Xsession to replace the desktop by an application. It's working fine. But when I go out from the game it returns to the LightDM - login screen. But I desire to shuts down instead back to LightDM. It's possible to do this?

Custom User Defined Session:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=RacingGameX
Comment=Just the game!
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/gameBash.sh
Type=Application
```

Bash Script:

```
xscreensaver -nosplash &
xrandr -r 60
exec /usr/bin/RacingGameX/RacingGameXExecutable
xrandr -r 75
sleep 5
sudo shutdown now # <- that's not working
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `exec` transfers control to the executable named behind it. As it stands, `sudo shutdown now` is never reached. You should remove `exec`. This may be just one obstacle on the way to the solution.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster. I see the difference now. I thought the command `exec` was to run an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for [`shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shutdown) from command line is

```
sudo shutdown -P now ## for system POWEROFF
sudo shutdown -h now ## for system HALT or POWEROFF
```

If that did not work we can also perform a forced poweroff

```
sudo poweroff --force
```

In case we start the script from a user session (as was the case in a custom session) we can either allow users to shutdown without root privileges (don't use `sudo` in your script then!) or follow answers to below questions to shutdown without root privileges from a user session:

- [Shutdown from terminal without entering password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168879/shutdown-from-terminal-without-entering-password)
- [How can I make shutdown not require admin password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Takkat! But that's commands line have tried and dont work. Btw I have followed your instructions in this question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application

Comment: @ulrich: totally missed that, sorry, you can't use sudo in your script - see edit.

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much @Takkat! I posted in the main post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I thank the members Takkat and David Foerster for the help. :)

The solution I've found:

If you have problem like this post, one solution is get the `consolekit` and insert the following code in your bash script to shutdown the system:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

The bash script will be:

```
xscreensaver -nosplash &
xrandr -r 60
/usr/bin/RacingGameX/RacingGameXExecutable
xrandr -r 75
sleep 5
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```